# How to resize control in IOS/swift

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose I have an image that is user supplied. I want to fetch and show this in **viewDidLoad()**. I intend to show this image as a logo in an UIImageView which spans the entire width. Underneath that I have another control I want to take all other parts of screen.

I have my image in an UIImage and I have resize-scaled its width to the same size as devicewidth*scale while keeping width/height proportions.

To handle the next step, I want to resize the UIImageView height, so its width/height proportions match my UIImage width/height propertions. (So the image is shown 100% corrrectly sized spanning enire width.)

I can do this by using UIImageView.frame but... **I have read frame usage will disable autolayout/constraints functionality** which I do not want to happen. I would just like to resize/set height once, but from then on rely on everything filling/resizing auomaically across phones / rotations.

I am in doubt what the recommended/standard way is of doing this as I am sill somewhat new to xcode/swift (I understand the code side of things now, but not so much the framework/behavior not having done anything visual yet)

Comment: Use autolayout constraints, not frame. Change the constraints at runtime if need be. There are constraints that will maintain aspect ratio, anchors, centers, relative width & height, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Autolayouts. Here is an [**official link**](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) .
 And [**really great tutorial**](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/) about it.
 And [**this article**](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/) if you want to use it programmatically.

**EDIT**

To keep width/height proportions for view (for any view, not only for UIImageView) you can use Aspect Ratio option of layout constraints. On the screenshot below I have added left, top and right spaces, and aspect ratio constraint, so width and height will be equal each other. This is 1:1 proportion:
[image]
This is how it looks with attached image (with Aspect Fill content mode for UIImageView):
[image]
Also, you can change ratio value, for example it can be 2:1 (2 for width and 1 for height):
[image]